# error with a form action post when inserting to a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

i have a problem with a form that has to post its data to a database. normally i this method works. but this time i get an error. i tried troubleshooting what could be wrong but i did not find the error.

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['userRole'] == 'leerling')
{
    if($_POST)
    {
        include "../dbCon.php";

        $naam = $_SESSION['name'];
        $dbtabel = "evaluatie";

        $vraag1 = $_POST['vraag1'];
        $vraag2 = $_POST['vraag2'];
        $vraag3 = $_POST['vraag3'];
        $vraag4 = $_POST['vraag4'];
        $vraag5 = $_POST['vraag5'];

        try
        {
            $objDB = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $dbhost .'; dbname=' . $dbname  ,  $dbuser ,  $dbpassword , array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
            $query = $objDB->query('SELECT * FROM '. $dbtable );
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            echo "1: Er is een fout opgetreden tijdens het verbinden met de database.<br />Namelijk: ".$e->getMessage();
        }

        try
        {   
            $objDB = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $dbhost .'; dbname=' . $dbname  ,  $dbuser ,  $dbpassword , array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
            $objDB->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $strSql = "INSERT INTO " . $dbtable . " (naam, vraag1, vraag2, vraag3, vraag4, vraag5)
               VALUES ( '" . $naam . "' , '" . $vraag1 . "' , '" .  $vraag2 . "' , '" .  $vraag3 . "' , '" .  $vraag4 . "' , '" .  $vraag5 . "')";
            $objStmt = $objDB->prepare($strSql);                    
            $objStmt->execute();
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            echo "2: Er is een fout opgetreden tijdens het verbinden met de database.<br />Namelijk: ".$e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    }
?>
```

when i view the page on my site i get an error

```
2: Er is een fout opgetreden tijdens het verbinden met de database. Namelijk: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(naam, vraag1, vraag2, vraag3, vraag4, vraag5) VALUES ( 'seppe' , 'Ik be' at line 1
```

does somebody knows whats wrong i cheched te code 10 times.

Comment: Can you show the whole query with the variables interpolated?

Comment: You don't need to include variables like that in an SQL query. You can simply do `$strSql = "INSERT INTO '$dbname' etc";`

Comment: Based on the error message, looks like you're not escaping `'` properly in your query

Comment: Just an observation, but what's the point of using PDO if you're not going to user query parameters? http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

If you using `query()` then like that:

```
$strSql = 'INSERT INTO ' . $dbtable . ' (naam, vraag1, vraag2, vraag3, vraag4, vraag5)
       VALUES (' . $naam . ',' . $vraag1 . ',' . $vraag2 . ',' . $vraag3 . ',' . $vraag4 . ',' . $vraag5 . ')';
$objStmt = $objDB->query($strSql); 
...
```

If you like to use Prepared Statements then you could use this approach:

```
 $strSql = 'INSERT INTO ' . $dbtable . ' (naam, vraag1, vraag2, vraag3, vraag4, vraag5)
       VALUES (:naam, :vraag1, :vraag2, :vraag3, :vraag4, :vraag5)';
 $objStmt = $objDB->prepare($strSql);                    
 $objStmt->execute(
    array(
      ':naam' => $naam,
      ':vraag1' => $vraag1, 
      ':vraag2' => $vraag2, 
      ':vraag3' => $vraag3, 
      ':vraag4' => $vraag4, 
      ':vraag5' => $vraag5  
    )
 );
```

Comment: Does all the fields exists with the right datatype and length?

Comment: id = int(11), naam = varchar(50), vraag1 = text,  vraag2 = text,  vraag3 = text,  vraag4 = text,  vraag5 = text.